# Big-O Notation Code Algorithm Analysis Homework

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

```
for(int i=N; i>0; i=i/2)  
    irrelevant statement;
```

I am asked to find the complexity class and I am unsure of whether I am supposed to use Big-Omega notation or Big-O? But I am assuming that it is O(N/2) and then O(N) if I drop the constants.

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)  
    for (int j = i+1; j<N; j++)  
        irrelevant statement;
```

For this one I believe it is O(N) * O(N+1) -> O(N^2 + N) and then O(N^2) after I drop the N?

Comment: After rereading the second code fragment, I changed my assumption to O(N) * O(N-1) instead of O(N) * O(N+1) because the nested loop gets iterated one less time than the first loop, is this correct? So it would be O(N(N-1)) == O(N^2-N) == O(N^2)?

Comment: deleted my original comment, as I misread the first loop. It is indeed O(log2(N))

Answer (score 3):

For the first one, how many more operations get executed if you double N?

Comment: If the N were doubled, you would have one more operation??

Comment: Steven: Right, so the complexity can't be O(N), because that would mean that the number of operations is proportional to N.

Answer (score 2):

The first one has complexity class O(log2(n)), as when you double n it only adds one more operation.

The second one is O((n^2)/2), or just O(n^2). The easiest way to understand this is to imagine it as a shape. You have two for loops, so you know that the ultimate complexity is n^2, but as the first continues, the second decreases to zero. This creates effectively a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the second one. First one is O(logN), and the second is O(N^2). But there is one *but*. What you refer to as `irrelevant statement` might be very relevant. If that statement were, for example a function call which in turn works in O(N), then the complexities would become O(N*logN) and O(N^3) respectively. So, you're right if the `irrelevant statement` is O(1).